# Создание бота Discord. Не могу понять, как запустить своего бота

Tags: python, консоль

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]Получается код для моего бота уже написан. Использую vs code. Также я уже добавил бота на сервер дискорда, но он сейчас не в сети. На ютубе множество видео, где его запускают через консоль, но т.к я ничего не понимаю и нахожусь в vs code(  а там все для меня пока что сложновато). В видео все используют Sublime text и запускают все через консоль. Собственно вопрос:в vs code нужно запускать через консоль? и если да, то как мне это сделать. Запустить саму консоль я могу, а от выбрать путь не получается, надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Как открыть консоль в [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal). Потом вводите **python имяфайла.py**. Если вы работаете в VS Code узнайте как с ним работать, чтобы хорошо в ней ориентироваться.

Upd: Сайт на английском, но в целом все довольно простыми словами. И начните учить английский т.к. в программировании почти весь материал на английском.